# What does $du^2$ notation mean in differential geometry?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm trying to read Lectures on quasiconformal mappings by Ahlfors, and I have trouble understanding some notation. I have a very basic understanding of differential geometry, so bear with me here.

On page 6 he takes a function $f(z) = u + iv$, $z = x + iy$, and writes

$du = u_x dx + u_y dy$

$dv = v_x dx + v_y dy$

and then says "in classical notation one writes"

$du^2 + dv^2 = (u_x^2 + v_x^2) dx^2 + (2u_x u_y + 2 v_x v_y) dx dy + (u_y^2 + v_y^2) dy^2$

I would like to thoroughly go through this as an exercise in differential geometry.

My understanding of the first equations is this: we have the tangent spaces at a specific point $z$ and $f(z)$, both of which are $\mathbb{R}^2$. We have the differential forms $dx, dy$ on the tangent space of the domain of $f$, which act by projecting a vector onto first/second coordinate, and these linear transformations between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ obviously also form a linear space. The function $f$ induces a linear transformation between these spaces, and it can be shown that it's given by these first two equations.

Now I'm a bit lost what he means here by $du^2$, because I don't think it's literally taking the square of $u$? And what object is $dx dy $, is that a wedge product? Basically the entire meaning of the last equation escapes me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is literally taking the square, as the expansion shows. $dx\,dy$ is the element of area in the $(x,y)$ coordinates.

Comment: I could be the symmetrization of the tensor product from the two 1-forms, i.e. $\mathrm d x \mathrm d y (v,w) := \mathrm{Sym} ( \mathrm d x \otimes \mathrm d y ) (v,w) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \mathrm d x(v) \mathrm d y(w) + \mathrm d y(v) \mathrm dx(w)\right)$? Then the equations reads as a equation for 2-froms. (I think something like this is defined in John M Lee's 'intro to smooth manifolds' book )

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm confused, isn't the left hand side a one-form? And shouldn't the right hand side be one as well then?

Comment: No, the differentials are squared.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok I just realized you meant he's taking the square of $du$ not of $u$ this actually makes sense. So am I correct that $du^2$ is not a 1-form anymore since it isnt linear, but it's just a function from the tangent space into $R$ given by the formula of squaring $du$?

Comment: Indeed. (And the differential $d(u^2)=2u\,du$ is also not a one-form.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you elaborate on that last point? Isn't $d(u^2) = 2u du = 2u u_x dx + 2u u_y dy$ a 1 form at each point given by this combination of the basis $dx, dy$?